# Права на каталог при монтировании SAMBA cifs на стороне клиента

Tags: fstab

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть настроенный сервер SAMBA выполняет функцию шары для клиентов. Сервер SAMBA CentOS7, клиенты то же CentOS7.

Через fstab монтирую шару cifs на клиенте в каталог/store.

До монтирования командой mount -a на каталоге /store были настроены нужные разрешения 
drwxrwsr-x. 2 root sales 6 Aug 17 08:00 /store/

После монтирования разрешения на клиентском каталоге меняются на 
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Aug 17 18:41 /store/
И пользователи в группе sales не могут изменять в каталоге.

fstab на клиенте:
//10.10.10.11/samba_share  /store cifs credentials=/user1 0 0

На сервер права на каталог шары настроены.
Как сделать так, чтобы разрешения на /store не переопределялись на каталоге после монтирования, а сохранялись до монтирования.

PS: на Windows клиенте права в соответствии с правами на сервере SAMBA. Т.е. все корректно.

Comment: права доступа к точке монтирования (каталог `/store` в вашем примере) не имеют никакого отношения к правам доступа внутри примонтированной файловой системы (т.е., к тому же каталогу `/store`, но после монтирования).

Comment: Это понятно. А как указать права на каталог на клиенте при монтировании в fstab. Например, мне нужно 2775

Comment: [*_mode](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs). но я бы рекомендовал разобраться — почему сервер не продоставляет эту информацию. потому что с большой вероятностью указанная манипуляция не даст ничего. ну, кроме изменения вывода программы ls.

Comment: А что нужно сделать на сервере, что бы он правильно предоставлял permissions на клиенте CentOS? Странно, но при доступе к шаре с Windows доступ для пользователя, указанного в файле конфигурации smb.conf,  в отличие от клиента CentOS для записи предоставлен. Исходя из этого, у меня складывается ощущение, что проблема в клиенте CentOS. Но куда именно копать - не знаю.